# Get values in from Get Request promies in SPFX

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, spfx, spfx-webparts

So I'm trying to get value from my result sources by using a GET request but I'm having trouble iterating to the items as they are under:
"PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.Table.Rows"

And I don't know how to retrieve from there so that I can display them

Get request :

```
export interface ProjectInformations {
PrimaryQueryResult: ProjectInformation[];
}

public render(): void {
this._renderPersonAsync();
}

private _renderPersonAsync(): void {
this._getData()
  .then((response) => {
    this._getSearchData(response.PrimaryQueryResult);
  });
}

private _getData(): Promise<ProjectInformations> {
  return 
this.context.spHttpClient.get(this.context.pageContext.site.absoluteUrl +
   `/_api/search/query?querytext='(GetDocument:"docx")'
  &selectproperties='Title%2cPath%2cProjectStatus%2cUrl'
  &sortlist='refinablestring08:ascending'
    &properties='SourceLevel:SPSiteSubscription,SourceName:Project'`, 
  SPHttpClient.configurations.v1, {
      })
    .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse): 
    Promise<ProjectInformations> => {
    return response.json();
    });
}
```

Solved it  by using alot of Export interfaces:

```
export interface ISearchResults {
PrimaryQueryResult: IPrimaryQueryResult;
}

 export interface IPrimaryQueryResult {
 RelevantResults: IRelevantResults;
 }

 export interface IRelevantResults {
 Table: ITable;
  }

 export interface ITable {
  Rows: Array<ICells>;
  }

 export interface ICells {
 Cells: Array<ICellsValue>;
 }

 export interface ICellsValue {
 Key: string;
 Value: string;
 ValueType: string;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

chain one more promise ie .then(()=>{}) and form an result array and return the result array

```
 if (data.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.Table.Rows) {
        var restResults = 
data.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.Table.Rows;
        var popularRestResults = new Array();

        for (var i = 0; i < restResults.length; i++) {
            var propertyResults: any = {};
            for (var j = 0; j < restResults[i].Cells.length; j++) {
                propertyResults[restResults[i].Cells[j]["Key"]] = restResults[i].Cells[j]["Value"];
            }
            popularRestResults[i] = propertyResults;
        }

        //create the ProjectInformations array by looping over popularRestResults and return the array
        return popularRestResults;
}
```

hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this example: [Link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37948.sharepoint-framework-retrieve-and-display-sharepoint-list-items-using-rest-api-and-react-js.aspx)